# Relationship between $\infty$-categories of ind-coherent sheaves on the base and total space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks

My question is vaguely as follows, let $G\to E\to X$ be a principal $\infty$-bundle for some group object $G$ in a category of ($\infty$-)stacks. Can we recover the category $\operatorname{IndCoh}(E)$ from the stable $\infty$-categories $\operatorname{IndCoh}(X)$, and $\operatorname{IndCoh}(G)$?

It is my understanding that by taking homotopical invariants of the category $\operatorname{IndCoh}(E)$ with respect to $G$ we can recover ind-coherent sheaves on the base (although I don’t know and would very much appreciate a reference for this). My question is: are there any tools to go in the opposite direction? (at least for some specific cases)

Comment: If $G$ is affine and we're in characteristic zero then one can use Gaitsgory's 1-affineness theorem to go recover categories with $G$-action (like $IndCoh(E)$) from their invariants, considered as $Rep(G)$-module categories (like $IndCoh(X)$), by tensoring with Vect over $Rep(G)$.